# Pass parameters SQL Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package with a variable (object) that takes its values in a script task (something like: letters{A,B,C,D}), and a foreach container that do something with every letter.

I want to create a job for this SSIS package. How would I pass the variable "letters" from the job? I want to add more letters in the list if I can; I want to create this variable from the job.

> example: letters{A,B,C,D,E}

I know that is something like this:

declare @l
set @l ='A'
select @l = '/SET \Package.Variables[User::letters].Proprieties[Value]'

Sorry if is not clear. I am not sure how to explain.

Comment: You need to create package parameters. Then you can provide values when you set up your job

Comment: yeah...but right now i have a list that i create it in a Script Task. How do i create it from the job. Because this list might have different numbers of parameters. (sometimes list might have 4 , sometimes might have 20). I have to add the parameters passed from the job in the list (in my variable)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to create a project param, and in the list of variable of your script task you pass your ($project)param. You also can define it as a required or not, hence when it's not informed in the job, you can define some logic in the package and assign a new value, like you said {A,B,C,D,E}.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something slightly different but I am making a big assumption.

You can define the values you want to loop through somehow. For this example, I will assume you can query your values.

Set a variable called LoopList as data type object.

Set var LoopItem as string

Exec SQL object:

1. Set data conn.
2. Set result set to Full Result Set
3. On Result Set Tab map that to LoopList variable
4. Add your query something like Select val from table or whatever.

ForEachLoop:

1. Collection is foreach ADO
2. Choose ADO source LoopList
3. Map LoopItem to Index0

Now you can run whatever you wanted to do without having to pass parameters.